# How to Add label On the top of the View Swift

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

**Here is what I am trying to do:**

[image: ScreeShot]

The screenshot is taken from iPhone:

[image: Screen Shot]

**Code Below:**

```
//Show HighLightView
    let highLightView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: self.minXHighLightView!, y: 0, width: self.maxXHighLightView!-self.minXHighLightView!, height: self.soundWaveView.frame.height))
    highLightView.backgroundColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 89/256, green: 206/256, blue: 249/256, alpha: 0.4)
    self.soundWaveView.addSubview(highLightView)

 //Show HighLight Lable
    let highLightLabelCount = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
    highLightLabelCount.textColor = .black
    highLightLabelCount.font = UIFont(name: "Lato-Bold", size: 20)
    highLightView.addSubview(highLightLabelCount)
```

**Question:** How to set Frame or constraints label setup at top Left Corner?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add the code and screenshot, if relevant.

Comment: Please Check @HunterCopp

Comment: label in top picture appears centered not in top left ?

Comment: top picture view width zero. you can see second picture view width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constraint should be centered x,y not top left with

```
//Show HighLightView
    let highLightView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: self.minXHighLightView!, y: 0, width: self.maxXHighLightView!-self.minXHighLightView!, height: self.soundWaveView.frame.height))
    highLightView.backgroundColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 89/256, green: 206/256, blue: 249/256, alpha: 0.4)
    self.soundWaveView.addSubview(highLightView)

 //Show HighLight Lable
    let highLightLabelCount = UILabel()
    highLightLabelCount.textColor = .black
    highLightLabelCount.font = UIFont(name: "Lato-Bold", size: 20)
    highLightView.addSubview(highLightLabelCount)
    highLightLabelCount.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

self.highLightView.textAlignment = .center
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
   self.highLightLabelCount.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.highLightView.centerXAnchor),
   self.highLightLabelCount.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.highLightView.centerYAnchor)
])
```

Comment: I m trying to your code but give me following error: Cannot convert value of type 'NSLayoutYAxisAnchor' to expected argument type 'NSLayoutAnchor<NSLayoutXAxisAnchor>'

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be useful if you would like to pin label to top left corner of your highlight view.

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        highLightView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
        highLightView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
        highLightLabelCount.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
        highLightLabelCount.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: highLightView.topAnchor))
        ])
```

Comment: I m trying to your code but give me following error:Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to activate constraint with anchors <NSLayoutXAxisAnchor:0x60000045f900 "UILabel:0x7fe8a746df40.leading"> and <NSLayoutXAxisAnchor:0x600000ba7b40 "UIView:0x7fe8a75522d0.leading"> because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.